# Is there evidence that women feel cold faster than men?

Tags: senses

There is a cliche saying that women freeze faster than men. Also, there have been several articles in health journals addressing this question. (e.g. this article:  "[Why women feel the cold more than men](http://www.bodyandsoul.com.au/health/health+news/why+women+feel+the+cold+more+than+men,13259)")

Is there any **scientific evidence** to support the claim **that women tend to feel cold faster than men?**

Comment: Are you sure this is the case? I think asking whether women tend to feel cold faster than men would be better. The answer - whatever it is - would come with the explanation.

Comment: I would recommend rephrasing this question as, "Is there any evidence to suggest women feel cold faster than men"?

Comment: Ok, I edited the question accordingly. @Kaadzia, I hope this is according to the spirit of your original question, feel free to let me know!

Comment: I changed the entire question to "Do women feel cold faster than men?" You're right, this should be the first question. The "why is this the case" can follow later. Please vote to reopen.

Comment: How is this question in any way related to health? It sounds like a much better fit for [Skeptics SE](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: "Why do women tend to feel cold more easily than men" is one of the [definiton questions for this proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66048?phase=definition). Also body temperature, the mechanisms regulating it and behaviours that affect it have an influence on a persons health.

Comment: @PatrickHoefler just because it fits on another site does not mean it doesn't fit here

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with Health. I think this question is off-topic.

Comment: @Tom Medley: Please see comment above (from  Apr. 3 13:40) Health includes "feeling well".

Answer (score 3):

Feeling cold can vary on our perception, age, race and hormonal concentrations.

This has been shown in [Gend Med study from 2007](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18215727):

> **More women than men had sensitivity to cold**. Whereas the percentage of men who had sensitivity to cold significantly increased with aging (P < 0.05), **the percentage of women who had sensitivity to cold was already high** (23.7%) at 50 to 60 years of age and did not change with aging.

Therefore based on the numbers we can say that sensitivity increases with aging and it is different in men and women. And this was not not associated with circulating hormonal concentrations.

These studies were tested only on Japanese men and postmenopausal women aged >=50 years, so if it's the evidence based on the numbers, it's up to you.

Comment: Answers like this are what our site aims for: concise, backed by reputable source, and answers the question. I'm currently at daily limit, but this has my +1. However, be careful of interpreting the study you cite correctly, and be cautious about the methodology involved.